# Cursor in textbox goes to wherever I click

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

Working on a site in ASP.NET, I have a textbox, and if I click in the middle of the textbox, when the textbox takes focus the cursor is in the middle, if I click 1/4 in from the left, on focus the cursor goes to 1/4 from the left.

I'm only having this issue with this particular textbox, all the other ones on my page function as expected (i.e., no matter where you click, the cursor defaults to the beginning of the textfield). Odd thing is that all textboxes are defined identically. The only thing that stands out about this one is that it is the last textbox on the page.

Any ideas?

There is no javascript on the page, although if that is the only way out of it I can use it.

Comment: Is this MVC 1, 2, 3, 4 , WebForms, Razor view? Also, are you drag and dropping a control textbox or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the lack of information here, I'm going to take an educated guess. I'm going to assume you are using asp.net Webforms.

[Webforms Textbox Control](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_textbox.asp)

> no matter where you click, the cursor defaults to the beginning of the textfield

This is because when a `Textbox` is clear of text (including white spaces) the beginning is at index 0.

What I'm thinking is causing your problem is white spaces being entered on that last Textbox control; go to the Properties for the `Textbox` control and under the `Text` property, click it and then press `CTRL-A` to select all characters (including white spaces) and press `DEL` to delete them all, if any.

Comment: Yes this was it, the issue was that data had gotten into the DB with whitespaces. I just did a `string.Trim()` after retrieving the data and this solved the issue.

Comment: @m1Lb4nKs Do you have your DB table fields defined as `nchar`? If so, that could be the issue. If you are not using unicode, Replace `nchar` with `varchar` and take off the `trim` from your code.